# Not able to find out null condition javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below code in javascript which finds out if value of Prov is null or not undefined
but unfortunately its not able to do so, and its able to update the value of `Prov`. what's wrong in the code below

```
 valid = () => {
    debugger;
    if (!this.state.Name && !this.state.ID) {
        if (!this.state.Prov) {
            debugger;
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                Prov: 'Please enter Province...'
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the above code, state is defined as below

```
 this.state = {
   Name: null,
   ID: null,
   Prov: null,
 }
```

Comment: Whats `this.state.STD` ?

Comment: Okay, so what will be the output if the `state` values are not null?

Comment: if (!this.state.Name && !this.state.ID && !this.state.Prov) {
        if (!this.state.Prov) { , whats the use of 2 `this.state.Prov` condition check?

Answer (score 1):

if your initial state is as below

```
 this.state = {
   Name: null,
   ID: null,
   Prov: null,
   }
```

your logic tries to check if it is null then add Prov, which is updating the Prov.
if you don't want to update the Prov when it has falsy values(null,undefined,0,NaN,false)  change this

```
        if (!this.state.Prov)
```

to

```
        if (this.state.Prov) {
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first if condition you wrote "stat" instead of "state" i think it should work let us know if it worked

Comment: Apologies, it was typo while posting in SO, corrected it..but problem still persists

Comment: what's the purpose of the second if? i mean we already know that `!this.state.Prov` is true

Answer (score 0):

Your values are nulls so when you do

```
 !this.state.<member name>
```

Its changing null to true (as boolean(null)=false and !false=true)
And if your this.state.Prov is undefined its also evalueating to true.
So all your if statements evaluating to true and so its updating the value.

Comment: So you've explained what happens in the `if` condition, but how is this the answer?

Comment: @Andreas check the question, and check my answer, i explained why his logic is not working

Comment: _"i explained why his logic is not working"_ - Only after my comment

Comment: @Andreas I explained why his logic isn't working before your comment, but more detailed, after it.

Answer (score 0):

because you will return true after PROV is set, even when Name and ID is not set, maybe?

```js
valid = () => {
    debugger;
    if (!this.state.Name && !this.state.ID) {
        if (!this.state.Prov) {
            debugger;
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                Prov: 'Please enter Province...'
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need an OR (||) case:

```
valid = () => {
    //check if any of these are empty 
    if (!this.state.Name || !this.state.ID || !this.state.Prov) {
        // if prov is empty
        if (!this.state.Prov) {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                Prov: 'Please enter Province...'
            });
            return false;
        }

        // if name is empty
        if (!this.state.Name) {}

        // if ID is empty
        if (!this.state.ID) {}
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the fileName in your code apart from the file name thing your code should have an else condition in the inner if that should set the province and return true.